# Run exec-maven-plugin on demand only

Tags: maven

Is there a way to configure maven (in general) or the exec-maven-plugin so that it is executed on demand only, but linked up to (and including) test?

I have a test main (java) that I use for ad-hoc testing. I can run it fine from within Eclipse. But I also want to run it from the command line.

However, I do **not** want it to run with the unit tests (test phase).

But it has to be staged after the test phase, because it uses code from the test subtree and it uses the test classpath.

Here is what I have. It works fine, except that it runs as part of the test phase.

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>adhoc-domain-test</id>
                <phase>test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>java</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <mainClass>com.abc.test.AdHocTest</mainClass>
            <classpathScope>test</classpathScope>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

If I change the phase to (eg) `verify`, it still gets executed on `mvn install`.

Comment: Just remove the `<executions>...</executions>` part from your pom and you can start it by: `mvn exec:java@adhoc-domain-test ...`...Furthermore define the exec-maven-plugin in pluginManagement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run a plugin on demand only, you can wrap the plugin inside a profile that is not active by default, like this:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>my-profile</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                ...
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

The `profiles` element goes directly under the `project` element. You can now run the plugin like this:

`mvn -P my-profile ...`

Comment: Thanks, that does the trick. I added the profile (with the exec plugin) at the end of the pom. One gripe is that it does not seem to be linked to the stuff outside any profile. `mvn clean ; mvn -P <prof> exec:java` does not build the project first. Another minor issue is that `mvn exec:java` (without activating the profile) seems to partially execute the exec plugin (error is: `'mainClass' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java are missing or invalid`

Comment: For the first issue, I think you have to specify a maven phase on the command line, e.g. `test` or `install`. If you kept the `execution` part of the plugin config, the plugin will be run in the phase given in the config, so you can omit `exec:java`. The second issue reflects that the plugin is only enabled for your profile, but that's the price you have to pay for not running it by default. :)